# How to find a kernel source code for ARM cortext-A55?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-parameters

I want to know how to find a proper Linux kernel source code for using ARM cortext-A55.
I got a kernel source code from kernel.org.

**But don't know how to "Config" my kernel to support specific "chipset" (for example Cortex-A55)**

There are many Kconfig settings in source code but not helpful.

Please let me know how to find it, or similar examples if any.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The linux kernel has support for Cortex-A55, including GCC tune profiles. The default Kconfig inside arm64 has entries for Cortex-A55

Comment: Cortex A-55 refers to a microarchitecture implementing a specific ARMv8 instruction set. What you need more than kernel config options is a (cross) compiler and associated toolchain that outputs code for this architecture. The kernel should be compiled with this compiler.